# Unity Editor Script Debugging Stack Trace Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a custom editor window I've made for a project I'm working on. Receiving this error when I hit breakpoints; 'error while processing request 'stackTrace' (exception: This request is not supported by the protocol version implemented by the debuggee.)'.

Unity Version 2018.4.11f1

Using Debugger for Unity Extension version 3.0.2 within Vistual Studio Code

Tried;

- Enabling full logs on Player Settings
- Adding UNITY_GIVE_CHANCE_TO_ATTACH_DEBUGGER system variable

Any help would be really great, thanks.